# TFS closes task after check-in associated to that task

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I check-in my pending changes, I add the work item ID under `Add work item by ID`. But this closes the task on TFS.

How can I prevent TFS from closing the task automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an option next to the work item for "Associate" or "Resolve". Change "Resolve" to "Associate".